# Filtering NHibernate Hierarchy using link tables

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Let's say I have a simple parent->child class structure as shown below

```
Public Class Parent
  Public ParentID As Integer
  Public Children As IList(Of Child)
End Class

Public Class Child
  Public ChildID As Integer
  Public Parent As Parent
End Class
```

These are mapped to two tables using Fluent NHibernate. No problem.

I now have a 3rd class, let's call 'User'. This class contains a list of Parent objects.

```
Public Class User
  Public UserID As Integer
  Public Parents As IList(Of Parent)
End Class
```

However, the list of parents should be filtered to the user by a mapping table (UserParentMap) which contains UserID and ParentID. Furthermore, the 'Child' objects should be filtered in a similar way by a table called UserChildMap which contains UserID and ChildID.

My question is - is it possible to get NHibernate to automatically use these mapping tables to filter the parent/child collection when mapping them to the user?

Thanks

James

Comment: I'm a little confused... are you talking about a many-to-many relationship here?

Comment: I don't think what I want to do is possible tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what I want to do is possible so I'm abandoning this question :)